# MediaWiki - How do I get the total number of Wanted pages?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

In MediaWiki it's possible to access the total number of pages that have been created with one of the magic words, `{{NUMBEROFPAGES}}`. Is there a way to access the total number of *wanted* pages, pages that are redlinked? There is Special:WantedPages, and if I go to the last page of results it has the total number. Does it find that only on request, or is that variable accessible in a similar way to `{{NUMBEROFPAGES}}`?

Comment: It is not. It's [not hard](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Magic_words) to add one if your wiki is small and you are not too concerned with performance.

Comment: Sick. Would you mind adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

That's not included in the [default magic words](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Statistics) and I'm not aware of any extension that would provide it, either. If you don't care too much about performance it is pretty easy to do:

```php
global $wgHooks;
$wgHooks['LanguageGetMagic'][] = function ( &$magicWords, $langCode ) {
     // 1 is for case-sensitive
    $magicWords['wantedpages'] = [ 1, 'NUMBEROFWANTEDPAGES' ];
};
$wgHooks['MagicWordwgVariableIDs'][] = function ( &$customVariableIds ) {
    $customVariableIds[] = 'wantedpages';
};
$wgHooks['ParserGetVariableValueSwitch'][] = function (
    &$parser, &$cache, &$magicWordId, &$ret
) {
    $db = wfGetDB( DB_REPLICA );
    $ret = $db->selectRowCount(
        [ 'pagelinks', 'page' ], // tables
        'count(*)', //value
        [ 'page_id' => null ], // conditions
        __METHOD__,
        [ 'GROUP BY' => [ 'pl_namespace', 'pl_title' ] ],
        [ 'page' => [ 'LEFT JOIN', 'pl_namespace = page_namespace AND pl_title = page_title' ] ] // join conditions
    );
};
```

Note that this is the extreme corner cutter version. If you are writing an extension and want to do it properly, see [the manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Magic_words).

Comment: This is surely useful, although I am not certain where it goes?

Comment: `LocalSettings.php` would be the conventional location (in that case you don't need the `global...` line it's in the global scope).

Comment: I added a ); to close selectField( and it parses correctly now. But it doesn't print anything when I write {{NUMBEROFWANTEDPAGES}}.

Comment: That is, it doesn't display a number when I write {{NUMBEROFWANTEDPAGES}} into a page on the wiki. It ignores the magic word and writes nothing there. Do I need to return $ret in some way? (return $ret; also causes nothing to be displayed)

Comment: No, it's a variable passed by reference (hooks work like Javascript event handlers: return false to abort processing, or anything else to continue). I'll test the code when I have some free time. What MediaWiki version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.26.3. Your help has been great.

Comment: Hm, it does give a result for me (although the result was wrong; fixed the query).

Comment: Well, with your most recent change, it's printing out `0`, which is incorrect, but at least it's printing something...

Comment: Well, if you want to debug it, the generated SQL should be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) numberofwantedpages FROM (SELECT  1  FROM pagelinks LEFT JOIN page ON pl_namespace = page_namespace AND pl_title = page_title WHERE page_id IS NULL GROUP BY pl_namespace, pl_title) tmp`.

Comment: ([page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table), [pagelinks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pagelinks_table))